# tengo que completar este analizador lexico en java y no se como continuar

Tags: java, tree

Tengo este programa de analizador lexico que obtiene los valores "b=x+5*6+4*7*8+3+4+5" desde la clase principal, y despues entra a la funcion "genera", donde crea un nodo "nodotree" con 3 valores: dato, izquierda y derecha. Crea el nodo raiz, crea un nodo izquierda con los datos del nodotree y despues crea un nodo derecha, donde entra al metodo "Expresion". En la primer linea entra al metodo "Factor", donde se crea otro nodotree, se regresa un valor T que es si el valor pos es menor a la longitud del caracter menos uno.

Intente depurar el programa pero es un poco tardado, no entiendo muy bien que esta sucediendo, porfavor ayuda.

```
package arbolexpresion;

class nodotree {

    char dato;
    String tipo;
    String lugar;
    String cod;
    nodotree izq, der;

    public nodotree(char d) {
        this.dato = d;
        this.izq = null;
        this.der = null;
    }
}

class arbol {

    nodotree raiz;
    static int pos;
    String[] temporales = {"T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7", "T8", "T9", "T10"};
    String[][] TS = {{"x", "Entero"},
        {"a", "String"},
        {"b", "String"},
        {"c", "String"},
        {"y", "Entero"},
        {"z", "Entero"}
    };
    int temp;

    public arbol() {
        this.raiz = null;
        pos = 0;
        temp = 0;
    }

    public void SetPos() {
        pos = 0;
    }

    public void preOrden(nodotree t) {
        if (t != null) {
            System.out.print(" " + t.dato);
            preOrden(t.izq);
            preOrden(t.der);
        }
    }

    public void inOrden(nodotree t) {
        if (t != null) {
            inOrden(t.izq);
            System.out.print(" " + t.dato);
            inOrden(t.der);
        }
    }

    public void posOrden(nodotree t) {
        if (t != null) {
            posOrden(t.izq);
            posOrden(t.der);
            System.out.print(" " + t.dato);

        }
    }

    public void GenCodigo(nodotree t) {
        if (t.dato == '=') {
            GenCodigo(t.der);
            System.out.println("mov " + t.izq.dato + ", " + "AX");
        } else {
            int queonda = cuantosson(t);
            if (queonda == 0) { //ningun hijo es hoja
                GenCodigo(t.izq);
                System.out.println("mov " + temporales[pos++] + ", " + " AX");
                GenCodigo(t.der);
                System.out.println("mov " + temporales[pos] + ", AX");
                System.out.println("mov ax ," + temporales[pos - 1]);
                if (t.dato == '+') {
                    System.out.println("add ax, " + temporales[pos++]);
                }
                if (t.dato == '*') {
                    System.out.println("mul ax, " + temporales[pos++]);
                }
            } else {
                if (queonda == 2) {  //ambos hijos son hojas
                    System.out.println("mov ax, " + t.izq.dato);
                    if (t.dato == '+') {
                        System.out.println("add ax, " + t.izq.dato);
                    }
                    if (t.dato == '*') {
                        System.out.println("mul ax, " + t.der.dato);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (queonda == 1) { //solo el hijo izquierdo es hoja
                        GenCodigo(t.der);
                        if (t.dato == '+') {
                            System.out.println("add ax, " + t.izq.dato);
                        }
                        if (t.dato == '*') {
                            System.out.println("mul ax, " + t.izq.dato);
                        }

                    } else { //Solo el hijo derecho es hoja
                        GenCodigo(t.izq);
                        if (t.dato == '+') {
                            System.out.println("add ax, " + t.der.dato);
                        }
                        if (t.dato == '*') {
                            System.out.println("mul ax, " + t.der.dato);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int cuantosson(nodotree t) {
        //ningun hijo es hoja
        if ((t.izq.izq != null) && (t.izq.der != null) && (t.der.izq != null)
                && (t.der.der != null)) {
            return 0;  //ningun hijo es hoja
        } else {
            if ((t.izq.izq == null) && (t.izq.der == null) && (t.der.izq == null)
                    && (t.der.der == null)) {
                return 2; //ambos son hojas
            } else {
                if ((t.izq.izq == null) && (t.izq.der == null)) //solo el hijo izquierdo es hoja
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return 3; //solo el hijo derecho es hoja
    }

    public void Intermedio(nodotree t) {
        if (t != null) {
            Intermedio(t.izq);
            Intermedio(t.der);

            if (t.izq == null && t.der == null) {
                t.lugar = t.dato + "";
                t.cod = "";
            } else {
                if ((t.dato == '*') || ((t.dato == '+'))) {
                    temp++;
                    t.lugar = "T" + temp;

                    t.cod = t.izq.cod + " " + t.der.cod + " "
                            + t.lugar + "=" + t.izq.lugar + t.dato + t.der.lugar
                            + "\n";
                } else {
                    if (t.dato == '=') {
                        t.cod = t.der.cod + " " + t.izq.lugar + "=" + "T" + temp;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }

    public void Verifica(nodotree t) {
        if (t != null) {
            Verifica(t.izq);
            Verifica(t.der);
            if (t.izq == null && t.der == null) {
                if (Character.isDigit(t.dato)) {
                    t.tipo = "Entero";
                } else {
                    t.tipo = Busqueda(t.dato + "");
                }
            } else {
                if (!t.izq.tipo.equals(t.der.tipo)) {
                    t.tipo = "0";
                } else {
                    t.tipo = t.izq.tipo;
                }
            }
        }



    }

    public String Busqueda(String cad) {

        for (int i = 0; i < TS.length; i++) {
            if (cad.equals(TS[i][0])) {
                return TS[i][1];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("la variable " + cad + " No esta declarada");
        return "0";

    }

    public void genera(String cad) {
        nodotree nuevo = new nodotree(cad.charAt(pos++));
        raiz = new nodotree(cad.charAt(pos++));
        raiz.izq = nuevo;
        raiz.der = null;
        raiz.der = Expresion(raiz.der, cad);

    }

    public void RealizaArbol(String cad) {
        raiz = Expresion(raiz, cad);
    }

    public static nodotree Expresion(nodotree t, String cad) {

        t = Termino(t, cad);

        while (cad.charAt(pos) == '+') {
            nodotree nuevo = new nodotree('+');
            pos++;
            nuevo.izq = t;
            nuevo.der = Termino(nuevo.der, cad);
            t = nuevo;
        }

        return t;
    }

    public static nodotree Termino(nodotree t, String cad) {
        t = Factor(t, cad);
        while (cad.charAt(pos) == '*') {
            nodotree nuevo = new nodotree('*');
            pos++;
            nuevo.izq = t;
            nuevo.der = Factor(nuevo.der, cad);
            t = nuevo;
        }
        return t;
    }

    public static nodotree Factor(nodotree t, String cad) {
        nodotree nuevo = new nodotree(cad.charAt(pos));
        if (pos < cad.length() - 1) {
            pos++;
        }
        t = nuevo;
        return t;
    }
}

public class principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] errores = {"variables no declarada", "Tipos incompatibles"};
        
        arbol miarbol = new arbol();
        miarbol.genera("b=x+5*6+4*7*8+3+4+5");

        miarbol.preOrden(miarbol.raiz);
        System.out.println();
        miarbol.inOrden(miarbol.raiz);
        System.out.println();
        miarbol.posOrden(miarbol.raiz);
        System.out.println();
        miarbol.SetPos();


//        miarbol.GenCodigo(miarbol.raiz);

    
    miarbol.Verifica(miarbol.raiz);
   if (!miarbol.raiz.tipo.equals("0"))
      System.out.println ("Todo esta bien");
   else
       System.out.println ("Hay incompatibilidad de tipos");

//miarbol.Intermedio(miarbol.raiz);
//System.out.println (miarbol.raiz.cod);
//    

    }
}
```